# access mysql database via Vb.net

Tags: vb.net

Im really confused as to whether what Im trying to achieve is possible and if there are better alternatives to it, so here it is:

Ive created web application for a business, it allows customers to view details etc, and most importantly make reservations.

These reservations are stored into a mysql database which all is provided by my web hosting service.

everything up to here is fine and without problems

The next thing im trying to achieve introduces complications:

So I am trying make a application which will run on only one machine, and its supposed to connect to that database and retrieve all those reservations.This is where Im trying to implement a Visual basic application.

The easiest way would off been to email the business  reservation every time its made, however this complicates things for the end user.It would be much easier to have an application that retrieves the data, simply on their desktop or a local drive as oppose to email.

I did research into vb.net and Net Connectors, but then came across the problem of my host not allowing remote connections to the database.

And this where Im stuck at now, I have no idea how to achieve the task

Thanks in advance for any guides or help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your web host will not allow a remote connection to the database then you wont be able make a WinForms application to sit on the customers desktop - as you've worked out.

> The simpliest solution is have a restricted Admin.aspx WebPage in the
>   website. This webpage would show all the reservations, allow Searching by From
>   and To Dates and possibly even allow for approval or rejecting bookings. This is a very common approach - I'd also recommend you have a special CSS for mobile phone webbrowsers so that your customers can view the bookings from their phone.

Comment: Thanks I might look into it, but  your interpretation is more complex than what I what. Customers cant view their bookings, there's no user management involved with customers or any user hierarchy for that matter. I simply want to make this VB application so that the bookings  are presented to the end user in a much more friendly manner, by which I can implement date filtering, searching,etc. I wanted an alternative to checking via email or having to create a user system on the site

Comment: User wants to "access bookings via desktop(internet) no need of going through emails, online sites etc as they lengthen the process and is not what we are looking for".